# using NHibernate on a table without a primary key

Tags: nhibernate

I am (hopefully) just about to start on my first NHibernate project and have come across a stumbling block. Would appreciate any advice.

I am working on a project where my new code will run side-by-side with legacy code and I cannot change the data model at all. I have come across a situation where one of the main tables has no primary key. It is something like this:

Say there is an order table and a product table, and a line_item table which lists the products in each order (i.e. consits of order_id, product_id, and quantity). In this data model it is quite possible to have 2 line items for the same product in the same order. What happens in the existing code is that whenever the user updates a line item, all line items for that order are deleted and re-inserted. Since even a compound key of all the fields in the line_item table would not necessarily be unique, that is the only possible way to update a line item in this data model.

I am prepared to guarantee that I will never attempt to update or delete an indivdual line item. Can I make my NHibernate code work in the same way as the existing code? If not, does this mean I (a) I cannot use NHibernate at all; (b) I cannot use NHibernate to map the line_item table; or (c) I can still map this table but not its relationships

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Personally I think you will struggle to get this working with NH.

Comment: Does adding an auto-incrementing ID column break the legacy app? (If it's bad enough to not have a PK column and do `DELETE`/`INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`, I'm assuming there's a greater-than-zero chance it could be doing `SELECT *` as well...)

Comment: From what I can tell, the existing app does do 'select *' but it seems to access the fields by name rather than index. However I'd really rather not risk messing with the data model just in case

Answer (score 0):

I think if you map it as a bag collection on the Order (with inverse="false") it would work.

[Collection Mapping](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/collections.html)

> Note: Large NHibernate bags mapped
>   with inverse="false" are inefficient
>   and should be avoided; NHibernate
>   can't create, delete or update rows
>   individually, because there is no key
>   that may be used to identify an
>   individual row.

They warn against it but it sounds like what you want.

Comment: thanks I will definitely try this out. I'm really keen to use NHibernate on this project, but if it can't handle this one relationship, it may be a showstopper to me.